# spread a map of key to list into key to single elements in scala

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I have this Map in Scala:

```
var m = Map(1 -> List("A","B","C","D"), 2 -> List("F","G","H","I"))
```

and I want to convert it on this:

```
var m = Map(1->"A", 1->"B", 1->"C", 1->"D", 2->"F",2->"G",2->"H",2->"I")
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Assuming your data is in a `Map` named `m` : `m.map {case (k, v) => v.map((k,_))}` should give something close to what you want.

Comment: The question is not clear. You want to turn your `Map` into a `List` of tuples? Is the order significant?

Comment: No the order is not important. @jrook solution is close to what I want. With his solution i got some like this: List(List((1,A), (1,B), (1,C), (1,D)), List((2,F), (2,G), (2,H), (2,I))).  i just need to convert to a map.

Comment: @GermanFarinas a **Map** can not have repeated keys... and if it could, how would you expect it to work? If you ask a value given its key, which one should it return?

Comment: Yes is true, sorry haha. I just realized that now. I guest I would leaved in a list of tupples. Thanks @Lu

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want:

```
val map = Map(1 -> List("A","B","C","D"), 2 -> List("F","G","H","I"))

val result =
  map.iterator.flatMap {
    case (key, values) =>
      values.map(value => key -> value)
  }.toList
// result: List[(Int, String)] = List((1,A), (1,B), (1,C), (1,D), (2,F), (2,G), (2,H), (2,I))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no solution because a map can not have repeated keys. The closest approach would be something like this:

```
m.map {case (k, v) => v.map((k,_))}.flatten
res215: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Int, String)] = List((1,A), (1,B), (1,C), (1,D), (2,F), (2,G), (2,H), (2,I))
```

Thanks to all and sorry for the question.